# Calculus: $f◦(g◦h)=f◦g+f◦h$ - Indirect reasoning

Tags: calculus, functions

"Is it true that $f◦(g◦h)=f◦g+f◦h$?"

I think I should use indirect reasoning to prove this but I don't know where to being. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally false I'd say following @mario 's example. Observing the statement

$$ f \circ g \circ h = f \circ g + f \circ h $$

Assuming an inverse exists for $f$ and associative/distrubutive poperties hold then:

$$ f^{-1} \circ f \circ g \circ h = f^{-1} \circ f \circ g + f^{-1} \circ f \circ h $$

hence

$$ g \circ h = g + h $$

Therefore the satement will only be true $iff$ our $g$ and $h$ satisfy the above.

Answer (score 2):

This is false, take $f=g=h=\text{ the identity function }$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, clearly $f\circ(g\circ h)(x)=x$ while $f\circ g (x) + f\circ h(x)=2x$.

Comment: Or let $f$ be nonzero constant ...